# How to detect keypresses with a .hta file whilst it is in the background

Tags: vbscript, hta

I know there are probably 10 questions with the same question however I have looked at them and have not found any useful answers from them.

I have a .hta script and it is like this.

```
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<script language="VBScript">

Dim objFSO, objFolder, objShell, objTextFile, objFile
Dim strDirectory, strFile, strText
strDirectory = "C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\Projects"
strFile = "\Project.txt"
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    If objFSO.FolderExists(strDirectory) Then
        Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(strDirectory)
    Else
        Set objFolder = objFSO.CreateFolder(strDirectory)
        WScript.Echo "Just created " & strDirectory
    End If

    If objFSO.FileExists(strDirectory & strFile) Then
        Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(strDirectory)
    Else
        Set objFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile(strDirectory & strFile)
    End If 

    set objFile = nothing
    set objFolder = nothing
    Const ForAppending = 8
    Set objTextFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile _
    (strDirectory & strFile, ForAppending, True)

    Sub CheckKey
     If window.event.keyCode = 112 Then
        objTextFile.WriteLine(Time & " - " & Date & ": ") & ("F1")
     End If
    End Sub
</script>
<body onKeyUp="CheckKey">
</body>
</head>
```

So it detects the key F1 (I used F1 for an example) and it puts it in a .txt file (so I know what has been pressed whilst testing).

However, there is a problem. When I press F1 whilst the .hta application is not selected it will not detect the key press. So I was wondering how to put it in the background so it will still detect the key press even when not on the application. If that is not possible, could I do it purely in a VBScript? - Thanks

Comment: You better search a real keyboard spyer, HTA is not suitable for that.

Comment: It is not for that use, I was wondering because I am create a custom keyboard short cut for a few programs that I use a lot.

Comment: No matter how you're going to use it, it's still a keyboard spyer, and can't be implemented with a script. If you're capable to write an ActiveX, you could use it in a HTA. Or try to search for a one.

Comment: Only active windows get keypresses. However apps can register hotkeys and windows can also register a different type of hotkey. They only way to access them without API calls is via shortcuts on the start menu or desktop (depending on Windows version maybe subfolders of the desktop as well). Right click a shortcut and in Properties set a hotkey. This registers an application hotkey to explorer. When pressed will ask explorer to run shortcut. Depending, a window opened by shortcut may have that key assigned to the windows as a window hotkey (so pressing will switch to the window).